# 404 Not Found while fetching OneDrive data from MS Graph Api

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to fetch the data via below api using admin access token the getting 404 error

**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx5f90/drive/root**

Below is the Error Response with 404 status code:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-e38bf8246e0a",
      "date": "2017-05-08T13:40:17"
    }
  }
}
```

Just FYI , the api works for an existing user using admin access token. But It does'not work a newly added OneDrive user with activated account.

Comment: Have this new drive been accessed via the browser at least once by the end user?

Comment: yes, the drive is accessed also few files uploaded to the drive. Actually got the issue resolved from settings pannel. We had to give permission to admin to access to the data of users files. The settings was done via the "site and settings" section of that User.

Comment: The solution to above can be automated as well to provide access to admin directly. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-eDiscovery-permissions-to-OneDrive-for-Business-sites-422858ff-917b-46d4-9e5b-3397f60eee4d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US